# How to change required Android version in Android Studio?

Tags: android

How can I change the minimum Android version required for my app once I've gone past the selection when I created a new project? Right now it's set on 5.1 and I would like to decrease it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Android Studio` you need to edit the **build.gradle**, i.e:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.pkg"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

In `eclipse` you can use the [uses-sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) on `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Comment: That's not the way to do it in Android Studio.

Comment: @TedHopp You're right, I'm still used to eclipse...Updated, tks.